# laravel on cpanel raise error for autoload_real.php on line 66

Tags: php, symfony, laravel-5, autoload, laravel-5.6

I am new to laravel and I run my website on localhost. It runs correctly but when I upload it on cpanel, it raises these errors :

> Warning:
>   require(/home/didfilei/public_html/app/vendor/composer/../symfony/polyfill-mbstring/bootstrap.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   /home/didfilei/public_html/app/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on
>   line 66
>
> Warning:
>   require(/home/didfilei/public_html/app/vendor/composer/../symfony/polyfill-mbstring/bootstrap.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   /home/didfilei/public_html/app/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on
>   line 66
>
> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required
>   '/home/didfilei/public_html/app/vendor/composer/../symfony/polyfill-mbstring/bootstrap.php'
>   (include_path='.:/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/usr/share/pear') in
>   /home/didfilei/public_html/app/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on
>   line 66

Comment: Did you run "composer install" on your web host after copying over your project?

Comment: i upload '/vendor' with project and in localhost i run composer install but said to me that 'nothing to update or install'

Comment: Are the php versions for localhost and your shared server the same?  Have you verified that your vendor upload worked i.e. checked for the existence of bootstrap.php?

Comment: my php version in localhost is '7.1.9' and in cpanel is '7.1.18', is this correct?

Comment: The versions are close enough though in general you should try to have your localhost match exactly.  Looks like your vendor directory did not upload correctly.  Would not be surprised if, after sorting the vendor issue, you encountered more problems with file permissions and such.  You could actually save yourself a tremendous amount of effort by using a cloud server such as digital ocean.  Good luck.

Comment: an issue occured that my cpanel in extract '/vendor' delete some folders like symfony!!! why??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved it. I realized that after extracting the zip file with cpanel, some folders were deleted (eg '/ symfony'), so I got more space from the hosts, then  my project extract correctly

Answer (score 2):

Since you do not have access to SSH, you should upload the vendor files along with the rest of your project. 
Be careful that if your dev machine is windows, you might face some issues with paths and case sensitivity.

You also need to check how php is executed in your host. You might have to fiddle around with file ownership and access rights. 
Especially if suphp is used, your user must be the owner of everything in your folder, all files must be set to 644 and all folders to 755

Comment: i uploaded '/vendor' but an issue is occured that in localhost in '/vendor' i have 36 folder but in cpanel i have 26 folder!!!

Comment: Try with FTP not zip or direct upload

Answer (score 1):

SSH into your server and run `composer update` in the root of your project. This will pull in the required vendor files that you are missing.

Comment: my cpanel does not permission for ssh ): and i do't have vps